# Array types with same element type & rank not equal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Very simple:

```
var equal1 = typeof(object[]) == typeof(object).MakeArrayType();
var equal2 = typeof(object[]) == typeof(object).MakeArrayType(1);
var equal3 = typeof(object[,]) == typeof(object).MakeArrayType(2);
```

The assumption is that all three should be true, but it turns out that `equal2` is `false` - which doesn't really make sense given that the first two `MakeArrayType` calls are equivalent and the resulting array types are the same.

> The only difference I can actually discern is that explicitly passing the rank of the array type as '1' yields a `Type` whose `Name` is `"Object[*]"` whereas omitting it yields `"Object[]"`.

So I thought, perhaps the rank of `object[]` isn't `1` (even though it clearly is!) - so I did this:

```
var type1 = typeof(object[]);
var type2 = type1.GetElementType().MakeArrayType(type1.GetArrayRank());
var equal = type1 == type2; //false
```

The types now definitely have the same rank, but are not equal.

> This scenario is more like my current scenario as I try to build Array covariance into Rezolver - so I'm recomposing array types by walking base hierarchies and using `MakeArrayType` with the original array type's rank.

So - can anyone explain why two array types with identical rank are not considered equal?

I realise there's likely some nuance I'm missing here, and that there are workarounds I can use, I'm just curious as to what's going on!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0ykk2sw(v=vs.110).aspx) explains the difference:

> The common language runtime makes a distinction between vectors (that is, one-dimensional arrays that are always zero-based) and multidimensional arrays. A vector, which always has only one dimension, is not the same as a multidimensional array that happens to have only one dimension. You cannot use this method overload to create a vector type; if rank is 1, this method overload returns a multidimensional array type that happens to have one dimension. Use the MakeArrayType() method overload to create vector types.

So basically, `equal1` returns a vector, and `equal2` returns a multidimensional array that happens to have a rank of 1.

The two types are treated very differently in the CLR.

Interestingly, if you create an *instance* of the type, you end up with a vector again:

```
var type = typeof(object).MakeArrayType(1);
// Create an instance with length 2
var array = Activator.CreateInstance(type, 2);
Console.WriteLine(array.GetType());            // System.Object[]
Console.WriteLine(type);                       // System.Object[*]
```

`Array.CreateInstance` shows the same behaviour: if you ask for an array with a lower bound of 0 and rank 1, it will always create a vector:

```
var array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 2 }, new[] { 0 });
Console.WriteLine(array.GetType());
object[] objArray = (object[]) array; // This is fine
```

If you change the 0 to any non-zero value, it will create a `System.Object[*]` and the cast will fail.

Comment: I imagine one ending up with a vector is an optimization on the part of the compiler since the `2` in this case would represent the size of the array [aka vector].

Comment: @Juan: The instance creation has nothing to do with the compiler though - it's the runtime/framework. It's very odd for `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` to create an instance of a *different* type.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. I misspoke. I meant to say the Runtime may be optimizing the operation. It's also possible the Activator has internal logic that determines you are requesting the equivalent of a vector. I will try to find the source and take a look when I get a chance. The point is, the determination is being made that the result is equivalent to a vector.

Comment: @Juan: Yes, that would make sense. It's still odd though :)

Comment: Yeah it is - I'm wondering if it's even physically possible to create an instance of a multidimensional array of rank 1 - which then begs the question why the type exists.  Smells a bit like a hack :)

Comment: I suspect the implementation of a vector must be better in terms of performance than that of a multi-dimensional array of rank 1 and the result must be functionally equivalent. I can't think of any other reason...

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: It certainly is possible if you don't have a lower-bound of 0. Not sure about otherwise - will investigate.

Comment: C'mon ppl. 1m rep for Jon :-)

Comment: @jonskeet of course - I'm thinking C# only here... An unacceptable presumption :)

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski If we were to play a game of "Code with C#" you can have [Anders Hejlsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) and I will take Jon Skeet. It's like knowing more about **C#** than Jon Skeet—it'll never happen no matter who you are.